# Передача Bitmap из C# в C++

Tags: c#, c++, bitmap

Собственно вопрос: каким способом можно передать изображение (Bitmap) Из программы, написанной на C# в библиотеку C++. Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: Ключевое слово - маршалинг. Посмотрите любые обёртки для С/С++ библиотек, например `curl`.

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так, обьявление инородной функции :) на С#

```
 public class NativeMethods
 {
 [DllImport("mylib_dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
 // если возвращает bool/int/long.. [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

 public static extern IntPtr myfunc(IntPtr mybitmap, int sizeOfBitmap);
 }
```

Использовать так:

```
  var aaa = NativeMethods.myfunc(bitmapBytes, bitmapBytes.length);
```